# How to include war in play 2 app?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, blogs

I have a play 2 Scala application and my customer wants to add a blog solution in a subfolder of this application. I came accross this java blog solution called [Apache Roller.](http://roller.apache.org/)

The issue is that I am not able to find it as a jar on maven repo to download it with sbt as we do with other libs because it comes as a war. Is there any way to use a war INSIDE a play 2 app? If yes, where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the Apache Roller team and thanks for considering our product.  Roller is meant to be a stand-alone web application, just configure your database, drop the WAR into Tomcat and you're set.  If desired, Roller offers an LDAP authentication option so users won't need a second set of passwords.  [Incidentally, while not yet released, our 5.1-SNAPSHOT is already considerably ahead of our current production 5.0.4 and is expected to be released "soon", so you may wish to consider that option.]  Trying to merge WARs will take an exceedingly long time and probably result in a buggy solution, so I would first confirm that your customers will not approve a separate application before trying to integrate blogging software.  The Roller User's Mailing List is available if you have any questions.

There is another Java solution, JBake, as it's not a standalone blog server like Roller you may find it more integratable in your web application.  (I have not worked with the product so am unsure.)  You may end up needing to create the blog entry edit screens, however, prior to feeding the results to JBake.